# How to find if the last message sent was by a specific bot account

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I want to check if the last message was sent by a specific bot. I already tried using `message.author.bot`, but this only returns whether it is or is not a bot, whereas I want to find if it is a specific bot. I also tried checking if `author.id` == `bot.user`, but this returns false. Is there a way to find if the last message was sent by a specific bot account?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check a specific bot, you can directly use the id. In fact, it shouldn't matter whether the returned `User` is a bot or not. I'm not sure what `bot.user` is meant to refer to.

```py
if message.author.id == target_bot.id:
```

Alternatively, just hardcode in the ID instead of tracking any `target_bot`.